# Bash: sort find results using part of a filename

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, find, webcam, cat

I have 3 webcams set up in a building, uploading still images to a webserver. I'm using ffmpeg to encode the jpgs to mp4 video.

The directories are set up like this:

```
Cam1/201504
Cam1/201505
Cam2/201504
Cam2/201505
Cam3/201504
Cam3/201505
```

I'm using the following bash loop/ffmpeg parameters to make one video per camera, per year. This works well so far (well... except that my SSD is rapidly degrading in performance - too many simultaneous read/write operations?):

```
find Cam2/2013* -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 cat | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 30 -vcodec mjpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 "Cam2-2013-30fps-19crf.mp4"
```

The individual files are named like this (confusing ffmpeg's built-in file sequencer):

```
Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

I now need to create one video for an entire year across all 3 cameras, ordered by timestamp. To accomplish this, I need to sort the find results by the segment of the filename after the underscore.

What do I pipe the find output to to accomplish this? For example, the files above would be ordered like this:

```
Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sort

```
sort -t '_' -nk2
```

`-t '_'` # specifices that the field seperator should be an underscore

-nk2 # start sorting from the second field (after the underscore)..`n` sort according to numerical value/timestamp

output

```
Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

pipe sort to find command like

```
sort -t '_' -nk2 --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` with the `--key` option. See your man page of `sort` for details of the key format. Generally (for both coreutils and BSD `sort`) it should be `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]`, where `F` is for field and `C` is for character position. Here you want to sort from the 5th character of the first field, so `--key=1.5` will do:

```
> echo -e 'Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg\nCam1_2015052413544601.jpg\nCam2_2015052413032601.jpg\nCam2_2015052413544901.jpg' | sort --key=1.5
Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

Here you seem to have not only basenames in the output of `find`, but relative paths with path segments like `Cam1/201505/` prepended, but you can still count the number of characters and hence write the appropriate keydef. For instance, say the paths for the images in the example above are

```
Cam1/201505/Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1/201505/Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2/201505/Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam2/201505/Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

Then

```
sort --key=1.17
```

will give you the correct order

```
Cam2/201505/Cam2_2015052413032601.jpg
Cam1/201505/Cam1_2015052413543201.jpg
Cam1/201505/Cam1_2015052413544601.jpg
Cam2/201505/Cam2_2015052413544901.jpg
```

Comment: This works for a shorter list, but I'm using xargs because I run into "/bin/cat: Argument list too long" with large lists. How would I integrate this into the command as written with xargs?

Comment: `find blah blah | sort blah blah | xargs blah blah`. What's wrong with that? By the way, the other answer is better than mine.

Comment: because this doesn't apply the sort. i guess i don't understand xargs that well. this is my command: `find */201111/*20111130* -name "*.jpg" -print0 | sort -t '_' -nk2 | xargs -0 cat | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 30 -vcodec mjpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 "output.mp4"`

Comment: You can't use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` when you're sticking a `sort` in between. `sort` relies on newlines.

Comment: $ `find */201111/* -name "*.jpg" | sort -t '_' -nk2`
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

Comment: the point is to concatenate the jpgs, then pass that to ffmpeg. i thought this might work, but i'm getting ": File name too long" `find */201111/*20111130* -name "*.jpg" -print | sort -t '_' -nk2 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' | xargs -0 cat`

Comment: I know. What I was saying is you should drop `-print0` in the `find` command and `-0` in the `xargs` command. As for the "argument list too long" for the `find` command, I suppose `find */201111 -name "*.jpg"` is enough. Adding a `*` at the end is pointless, because `find` iterates through them all anyway.

Comment: By the way, you probably don't even need `find`. Assuming I understood your directory structure correctly, you can simply `echo */201111/*.jpg | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -t '_' -nk2 | xargs cat`. `echo` is a shell builtin and isn't subject to `ARG_MAX`, the maximum length of a command line.

Comment: Eureka! You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.